# React does not re-render when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of warehouses that I pull from an API call.  I then render a list of components that render checkboxes for each warehouse.  I keep the state of the checkbox in an object (using the useState hook).  when I check/uncheck the checkbox, I update the object accordingly.

My task is to display a message above the checkbox when it is unchecked.  I tried simply using the object, however, the component was not re-rendering when the object changed.

I found a solution to my problem by simply adding another useState hook (boolean value) that serves as a toggle.  Since adding it, the component re-renders and my object's value is read and acted on appropriately.

My question is: why did I have to add the toggle to get React to re-render the component?  Am I not updating my object in a manner that allows React to see the change in state?  Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

I've created a sandbox to demonstrate the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-bhabha-lk61n

```
function App() {
  const warehouses = [
    {
      warehouseId: "CHI"
    },
    {
      warehouseId: "DAL"
    },
    {
      warehouseId: "MIA"
    }
  ];

  const [warehouseStatus, setWarehouseStatus] = useState({});
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (warehouses.length > 0) {
      const warehouseStates = warehouses.reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc[item.warehouseId] = true;
        return acc;
      }, {});
      setWarehouseStatus(warehouseStates);
    }
  }, [warehouses.length]);

  const handleChange = obj => {
    const newState = warehouseStatus;
    const { name, value } = obj;
    newState[name] = value;
    setWarehouseStatus(newState);
    setToggle(!toggle);
  };

  return warehouses.map((wh, idx) => {
    return (
      <div key={idx}>
        {!warehouseStatus[wh.warehouseId] && <span>This is whack</span>}
        <MyCheckbox
          initialState
          id={wh.warehouseId}
          onCheckChanged={handleChange}
          label={wh.warehouseId}
        />
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating state ([don't mutate state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state))

this:

```
  const handleChange = obj => {
    const newState = warehouseStatus;
    const { name, value } = obj;
    newState[name] = value;
    setWarehouseStatus(newState);
  };
```

should be:

```
  const handleChange = ({name,value}) => {
    setWarehouseStatus({...warehouseStatus,[name]:value});
  };
```

See the problem?

```
    const newState = warehouseStatus; <- this isn't "newState", it's a reference to the existing state
    const { name, value } = obj;
    newState[name] = value; <- and now you've gone and mutated the existing state
```

You then call `setState` with the same state reference (directly mutated). React says, "hey, that's the same reference to the state I previously had, I don't need to do anything".

Comment: Thanks so much! That makes sense now.