# Why is my array not updating when I set state in react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update this array dynamically as a dropdown but it shows up as empty

```
 const setCountries = async (e) =>{
    if(e != null)
    {
      const countries = await survey.retrieveCountries(e);
      let tmpArray = [] as any;
      for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
         tmpArray.push(countries[i].name)
      }
      setCountryDropdown(tmpArray);
    }
  }
```

```
<Multiselect
            options={countryDropdown} // Options to display in the dropdown
            displayValue="Countries To Field" // Property name to display in the dropdown options
            onSearch={(e) => setCountries(e)}
            />
```

Comment: Did you use a library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React does not re-render when state changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59583520/react-does-not-re-render-when-state-changes)

Comment: The cast to any is at least suspicious.

What does `retrieveCountries` expect? What does that function return?

Comment: Without knowing how `Multiselect` is implemented or what you've tried to confirm it's not changing, I think this question needs more supporting information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the demos](https://codesandbox.io/s/10xn41w767), it seems if you're using a plain array of strings for your options you have to use `isObject={false}` as a prop for Multiselect:

```
<Multiselect options={plainArray} isObject={false} />
```

If you don't it bugs out, making it seem that the options are empty.